# imageSX and imageSY VS getimagesize

Tags: php, getimagesize

I need to receive the width and height of an image.

What kind of function do I have to use?

Will `imageSX(Y)` be quicker than `getimagesize()`?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

`getimagesize ( string $filename [, array &$imageinfo ] )` should logically be faster.

**Long Answer:**

`getimagesize()` gets size, image all at once with 1 single file read, meaning the cost of the function is just 1 file read with some computation, while both `imagesx()` and `imagesy()` are 2 individual calls, meaning when whoever code these functions should consider reading the image file and measure the size separately. Hence in your case, if you intend to get both width and height, using `imagesx()` `imagesy()` would likely cost you 2 file reads. One thing for sure is that one programmer cannot be sure about the function be called once or more, so what he/she can do is to read the image every time the function is called. With disk I/O being one of the high-cost items in runtime, 2 times is definitely slower than once.

From a memory perspective, both functions take the whole image to RAM so there's not much for the input, but for the output, an array from `getimagesize()` is definitely larger than 2 `int` from `imagesx()` `imagesy()`. Just in case someone would care about instantaneous memory usage...

Comment: I thought the argument to imagesx was an in-memory object, hence no "file read".

Comment: Hi Rick James, from my understanding, the imagesx() or imagery() function takes a GDImage resource before the PHP8 update, which now takes a GDImage object. Since resources are like blobs, the storage media may also depend on memory settings in php.ini config file, default is disk cache for GD.

Reviewing this 2 years later, I think a better answer would be depending on the coding situation for whether you have this image as a GD instance already or is just a filename as a string. If you already had a GD on hand, then it makes more sense to use the 2 functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imagesx()` if you already have an `image resource` as defined in their [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php).

If you are getting the image from a file, you should consider using `imagecreatefromstring()` using the image file's data string, as in their [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).